# converting php code to html

Tags: php, html, type-conversion

I have been having hard time trying to convert my php code to html for 5 hours and at this point, I'm really burned out :X. 
Here's my Php code

```
 <?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","pw","dbname");
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablea");

 echo "<table border='1'  >
 <tr>
 <th>id</th>
 <th>Subject_Code</th>
 <th>date</th>
 <th>name</th>
 <th>description</th>
 <th>Other_Details</th>
 </tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Subject_Code'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td width='600' class='table_width'>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td width='600' class='table_width' align='center'>" . $row['Other_Details'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
 echo "</table>";

 mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

and here's what i have done so far for HTML

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>database connections</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php
      $username = "dbuser";
      $password = "pw";
      $host = "localhost";
      $database= "dbname";

      $connector = mysql_connect($localhost,$dbuser,$pw,dbname)
          or die("Unable to connect");
        echo "Connections are made successfully::";
      $selected = mysql_select_db("test_db", $connector)
        or die("Unable to connect");

      //execute the SQL query and return records
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablea ");
      ?>
      <table border="2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>Subject_Code</th>
          <th>date</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>description</th>
          <td>Other_Details</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['Subject_Code']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Other_Details']; ?></td>
        </tr>

     <?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

little Help here please, Thanks !!

EDIT: seems like some people are not understanding my question. My php is working fine so i want to convert the php code into html. Basically, i want my table from database to show up using HTML table.

Comment: help to do what? what are you asking?

Comment: what is your problem with code  . what you want achieve ?

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: My php is working fine so i want to convert the php code into html. Basically, i want my table from database to show up using HTML table.

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: nope,just a table with no data.

Comment: so problem is your not fetching data from database . whta is your table name  ?

Comment: yes probably, the table name is tablea. my php file with the php code works fine, but not the html.

Comment: as you said your html version why your using mysql insted of mysqli . why the api get differ in above two codes ? that's not main reason but mysql_* is deprecated try to use mysqli_*

Comment: oh i already changed it to mysqli_ too

Comment: <?php
ini_set("display_errors", "1"); ?> on top of the page and on the error debug mode

Comment: try this first check value come from database or not like this $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablea ");  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);   print_r($row); exit;

Comment: try my updated answer @JessicaLim

Answer (score 1):

you not close while;

so change code to :

```
    <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>database connections</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <?php

/////////////////////////////////// change \\\
          $username = "dbuser";
          $password = "pw";
          $host = "localhost";
          $database= "dbname";

          $connector = mysql_connect($localhost,$username,$password)
              or die("Unable to connect");
            echo "Connections are made successfully::";
          $selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connector)
            or die("Unable to connect");

    /////////////////////////////////// end change \\\

          //execute the SQL query and return records
          $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablea ");
          ?>
          <table border="2">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>Subject_Code</th>
              <th>date</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>description</th>
              <td>Other_Details</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) :
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row['Subject_Code']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Other_Details']; ?></td>
            </tr>
         <?php endwhile;?>
         <?php mysql_close($connector); ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: change connect db for not mach php code.pls,chack code

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem is as you said like html version there is no variable like `$localhost` but your passing the parameter to connect mysql etc. below error code shows the variable mismatch of your code.

**Error code :**

```
<?php
  $username = "dbuser";
  $password = "pw";
  $host = "localhost";
  $database= "dbname";

  $connector = mysql_connect($localhost,$dbuser,$pw,dbname);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  //here there is no variable like what you passing to connect mysql that's problem here 
  ?>
```

**solution :**

```
         <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>database connections</title>
        </head>
        <body>

    <?php
      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","pw","dbname");
     // Check connection
     if(mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       }

     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tablea");

     echo "<table border='1'  >
     <tr>
     <th>id</th>
     <th>Subject_Code</th>
     <th>date</th>
     <th>name</th>
     <th>description</th>
     <th>Other_Details</th>
     </tr>";

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {
            echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['Subject_Code'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='600' class='table_width'>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='600' class='table_width' align='center'>" . $row['Other_Details'] . "</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
       }
     echo "</table>";

     mysqli_close($con);

     ?>

       </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: just tried that and it just shows the code instead, not even a table :X.

Comment: what is file name with extenstion filename.php or filename.html ? @JessicaLim

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version that makes use of PDO - by far the superior of php connectors in terms of maintainability and versatility. I have the same code working under MySQL, SQLite and SQLServer - the only thing that changes is the connection string.

You'll note I pull all of the results at once. I also make use of the fact that we get back an array. Each element of that array is a row. Each row is an array of cells. This greatly reduces the code needed to output a result-set. We just need two forEach loops and that's it.

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $userName = 'dbuser';
    $password = 'pw';
    $nameOfDb = 'dbname';
    $nameOfTable = 'tablea';

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host, $userName, $password);
    $pdo->query("use " . $nameOfDb);

    // desired results requested explicitly, so when we get an array for the row's data, the elements will be in the same order
    // - not required if the order of the columns in the database matches the desired display order. (we could just use 'select *' then)
    //$query = $pdo->prepare('select * from '.$nameOfTable);
    $query = $pdo->prepare('select id, Subject_Code, date, name, description, Other_Details from '. $nameOfTable);

    $query->execute();
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $rows = $query->fetchAll();
?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th><th>Subject_Code</th><th>date</th><th>name</th><th>description</th><th>Other_Details</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody><?php
                forEach($rows as $curRow)
                {
                    echo '<tr>';

                        // use this one if you want to display the columns in the same order they are returned in the query results
                        // AND you'd like to display all columns in the result
                        forEach($curRow as $curCell)
                            echo '<td>'.$curCell.'</td>';

                        // otherwise, you can request the desired elements by name
                        //
                        //  echo '<td>' . $curCell['id'] . '</td>'
                        //  echo '<td>' . $curCell['Subject_Code'] . '</td>'

                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            ?></tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download HTTrack Website Copier and install and run the soft. Run your script and paste your URL in web copier software. You will get HTML output in your desire folder